# Do play framework messages files support comments?

Tags: playframework, internationalization

Does anybody know if the messages / messages.xxx files support comments? If yes, which is the tag to declare a line as comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is. Begin the line with `#`

```
# Here is a comment
message.key=Message value
```